# Связка двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Я уже много дней пытаюсь связать две таблицы users и friends, вот сами таблицы и их содержимое:
users
id (идентификатор) остальное не важно
friends
id u_1(идентификатор первого юзера) u_2(идентификатор второго юзера) status (статус их дружбы, если 1 то дружат, если 0 то нет).

Мне нужно вывести список друзей у определённого пользователя, чтобы у тех id у которых статус 1, выводились в див.
Мне нужен сам sql запрос, с остальным я справлюсь, хелпуйте!![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну и? где ваш запрос?

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0):

связать две таблицы можно с помощью left join, в запросе указывается по какому полю они связываются (on ). После имен таблиц можно поставить алиасы (псевдонимы,клички) для удобства.
Далее where ставится условие по которому производится фильтрация записей.

```
select * from 
users u
left join friends f on f.usersid = u.usersid
where u.status = 1
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]